# How do you wrap a global function in javascript without anyone detect it?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious how some website prevent you to download its video ( only for study purpose ).

I start by wrap `window.MediaSource.addSourceBuffer`. But some how the website detect it. Here's the wrapper code :

```js
let _addSourceBuffer = window.MediaSource.prototype.addSourceBuffer
window.MediaSource.prototype.addSourceBuffer = function(mime) {
    return _addSourceBuffer.call(this, mime)
}
```

How do you detect such wrapper in javascript?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, we can't guess which the site might be using. One obvious one is invoking `toString` on `window.MediaSource.prototype.addSourceBuffer`. It should return something like `"function addSourceBuffer() { [native code] }"` but yours will return the function body you've defined.

Comment: I thought about this actually.  Is there any other way of detect such wrapper?

Comment: Are you sure they do detect it at call time? Is your script running before theirs? Can you link to the website?

Comment: How do you detect it not on call time? and my script is a tampermonkey script, they don't detect it as far as I don't override `MediaSource.addSourceBuffer`. I switch the setting to `load on document start`. And currently I not able to put the link, because it is not public yet...

Comment: They could have overridden the setter themselves and detect that you were trying to do it too. But without a clear error message, nor any code to chew on, we really can't help you here.